# Heroku app Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, web-hosting

I have deployed a selenium WebDriver app to Heroku, but it keeps crashing due to exceeding maximum memory given to a dyno, how to increase memory of a dyno or fix this issue,

[image: example]

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: no mate, my app was using too much ram, possibly due to a memory leak.

Comment: Well I haven't found any solution to decrease memory usage, but selenium use more memory as more and more tab opens.. So if you're only working on 1 or 2 tabs and there are more tabs getting creating because of ads of something then closing driver and reinitializing may help!
I don't know what application you're running on it or how it's working out but the above one was my case!

Comment: Yeah, thanks mated, I got that noted.